# My React app is using values from the .env file instead of the .env.local file

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv, craco

The `dotenv` module [should be](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) prioritizing my `.env.local` file over my `.env` file, but it's not. When I have `REACT_APP_API_BASE` set in both files, the app always uses the value in `.env`. It only uses the value in `.env.local` if I delete the matching definition in `.env`.

---

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE = 'https://api-staging.mysite.com/api'
```

---

**.env.local**

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE = 'https://api-qa.mysite.com/api'
```

---

*The app is making API calls to https://api-staging.mysite.com/api/endpoint.*

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, I'm not running `react-scripts` directly, I'm using CRACO.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.2.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.2.2",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.14.0",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.3.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.0",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-intl": "^5.10.14",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@formatjs/cli": "^3.0.1",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/components": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.20",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.35.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "babel-plugin-formatjs": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.5.0",
    "hint": "^6.1.1",
    "jest-chain": "^1.1.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "formatjs",
        {
          "idInterpolationPattern": "[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]",
          "ast": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
```

Comment: why you want to use .env.local instead of .env ?
.env.local or .env.example includes the examples and variables used in the project

Comment: Because I want to temporarily overwrite the project defaults (or add in security tokens that shouldn't be saved to git).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Five minutes after posting a bounty, I finally figure it out...*

One of my files had `require('dotenv').config();` at the top. Apparently, this was overwriting the configuration found by CRA with whatever was in the main `.env` file. Once I **deleted that line from my code**, everything worked fine.